# Проверить адресную строку

Tags: javascript

Хочу чтобы на разных языках отображалась кнопка лайк (facebook), пробовал следующим образом:

```
if(window.location.href == '/lv/'){
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/lv_LV/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=491659391035911";
}else if(/ru/.test(window.location.href)){
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=491659391035911";
}else if(/lt/.test(window.location.href)){
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/lt_LT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=491659391035911";
}else if(/et/.test(window.location.href)){
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/et_EE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=491659391035911";
}else{
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=491659391035911";
}
```

Так работает не корректно, например вместо английского выводит литовский, посоветуйте, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Для начала посмотрите что у вас в `window.location.href`. Скорее всего вам нужен `location.pathname`, но даже в этом случае нельзя проверять точное совпадение довольно глупо.

Comment: А Facebook не может сам детектить?

Comment: site.ru/ru/postname примерно так

facebook сам не детектит

Answer (score 1):

Пока мы не знаем что у вас в `window.location.href` это стрельба по воробьям.

```
//var url = window.location.href ;
//url = "www/ru/index.html?some=param"; // Для примера
//url = "www/lv/index.html?some=param"; 
url = "www/et/index.html?some=param"; 

if(new RegExp("site[.]ru\/lv\/").test(url)){
alert("lv");
}else if(new RegExp("site[.]ru\/ru\/").test(url)){
alert("ru");
}else if(new RegExp("site[.]ru\/lt\/").test(url)){
alert("lt");
}else if(new RegExp("site[.]ru\/et\/").test(url)){
alert("et");
}else{
alert("else");
}
```

[Поиграться тут](https://jsfiddle.net/bvmbt6yn/), нажать на кнопку Run вверху